# Como remover a parte vermelha da figura?

Tags: php, mysql, array, array-multidimensional

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
require("setup_do_banco.php");

$colunas    = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM origem WHERE ativado = 1");
$colunas->execute();

while ( $coluna = $colunas->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) { $array_banco = $coluna; }

foreach($array_banco as $item){

    $fields[] = sprintf("'%s' => '%s'", $item['field'], $item['description']);

}

$array = array (
    'key'       => '8b0dc65f996f98fd178a9defd0efa077',
    'module'    => 'imoveis',
    'method'    => 'busca_imoveis',
    'field'     => $fields
);

$client = new SoapClient(null, array (
    'uri' => 'http://soap.imo.bi/',
    'location' =>
    'http://soap.imo.bi/soap.dll',
    'trace' => 'trace'
    )
);
```

> **Atualização 1**

***Acho que o código abaixo é mais correto, certo?***

```
require("setup_do_banco.php");

$colunas    = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM origem WHERE ativado = 1");
$colunas->execute();

$array_banco = $colunas->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($array_banco as $item){
    ###############################################
    $fields[$item['field']] = $item['description'];
}

$array = array (
    'key'       => '8b0dc65f996f98fd178a9defd0efa077',
    'module'    => 'imoveis',
    'method'    => 'busca_imoveis',
    'field'     => $fields
);

$client = new SoapClient(null, array (
    'uri' => 'http://soap.imo.bi/',
    'location' =>
    'http://soap.imo.bi/soap.dll',
    'trace' => 'trace'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acho que você quer fazer isto:

```
foreach($array_banco as $item){
    $fields[$item['field']] = $item['description'];
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/AfeQ1p). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gewmoaye-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Array/ForEach.php).

Esse `while` antes do `foreach` não parece fazer sentido algum. Até funciona, mas por coincidência.

Comment: Eu tenho isso `[DATA] => 'Data cadastro'` conseguimos isso `'DATA' => 'Data cadastro'` o campo **field** com aspas simples em vez de colchetes? ... senão o SOAP não reconhece o comando.

Comment: Você precisa explicar melhor o que você quer então.

Comment: Mas não é só isso o `$array_banco = $coluna;` também parece estar errado.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento ao que eu percebi (mas não testei), não chega estar errado, só desnecessário. Pelo que pude concluir é que a `$coluna` recebe todo o *array*. Como deu certo, entra no `while` e joga `$coluna` para `$array_banco` (por que não usa `$coluna` logo então?) e depois não continua o *loop* porque logo após não há mais nada para dar *fetch*.

Comment: @bigown posso estar confuso, mas com o `while` ele só vai atingir a ultima linha da lista, ou seja, sendo uma lista de imóveis, ele está apenas a pegar o ultimo e isto não parece ser o correto, já que ele está trabalhando com um "WebService de carga de imóveis", ao menos é o que me parece.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento dê uma olhada na documentação da `fetchAll`, ela não faz o que você supõe. Simplesmente toda esta linha é desnecessária, basta transportar a chamada da função onde ela é necessária.

Comment: @bigown entendo, eu não percebi que era `fetchall`, realmente está correto, foi talvez algo apenas *desnecessário*. +1